# how to compare value of a row in a table with sum of colum in another table in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have to tables, i want to select all from table1 where amount is less than the sum of a column in table2.

Please how do i do this in sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Tested. Just scribbled something in Notepad. Please try this -

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.amount < (SELECT SUM(column2) FROM table2)
```

Comment: That will incur a lot of extra computing resources, scanning the entire table in the sub query once for each row in table1.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Below is what i already tried:  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1 .amount < (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table2 WHERE table2.tb_id=table1.tb1_id)

Comment: @HarrisonOziegbe - What is the problem with the one which you have already tried? I mean, what more are you looking for? If there is an error then please post it here.

Comment: @HarrisonOziegbe - Can you please accept the answer if that's where you got the idea from?

Comment: The problem is, the row display whether table1 amount is grater than sum of table2 column.  Is there any other method i can use to archive this?

Comment: @HarrisonOziegbe - Try to understand this - You have modified the query to add the additional condition `table2.tb_id=table1.tb1_id` in the sub query which gets the `SUM(amount) FROM table2`. This makes the inner query a co-related sub query and will check the `amount` in `table1` against the `SUM(amount)` for only those rows `WHERE table2.tb_id=table1.tb1_id` in `table2`. This will not make sense if `table2.tb_id` is **UNIQUE** in `table2`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT sum(amount) FROM Table2) t_agg2 ON t_agg2.total > t1.amount;
```